# Why Image inserts different value in bytes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column of type `Image` and I'm trying to insert the value in bytes using a SQL query like this:

```
INSERT Into DocumentImage (FileName, DocImage, DateTimeAdded)
VALUES ('TestTemp.xlsx', 
        '0x504B030414000600080000002100ECC0AA13A901000035070000130008025B436F6E74656E745F54797065735D2E786D6C20A2040228A0000200000000', 
        GETDATE())
```

But after inserting the `Image` value changes to some other bytes like this

```
'0x30783530344230333034313430303036303'
```

Any idea why this is happening or how can I store the expected value? Would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. **Avoid using this data type** in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Try removing the quotes. Your value is implicitly converting the string value you passed in to its varbinary interpretation, rather than treating it as an actual varbinary value

Comment: Actually I'm not allowed to change the data type here

Comment: The quoted `'0x504B0304...'` value is a character string, and those characters are being converted to the quivalent byte representation - `0x30783530...`. If you unquote the value as `0x504B0304...`, you actually have a binary literal and you should then get your expected results.

Comment: If someone has suggested you can't change the datatype, you should strongly object pointing to the relevant documentation as to why its a bad idea.

Comment: *"Actually I'm not allowed to change the data type here"* why not? Why are you *forced* to use a data type that has been deprecated for *almost **20 years*** ago?

Comment: @DaleK Another reason to just change the data type regardless of vendor's recommendations: there is implicit conversion in both directions, so unless the software is *specifically* looking for `image` it will Just Work.

Comment: @TN If you need to convert a `varchar` that represents a binary value to a `(var)binary` you can just use `CONVERT` with a style code, no need for xquery. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k6r_QQCm)

Comment: If you have input data that is already encoded as a hex string, the hex string to binary conversion could be done with either `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @HexString, 1)` or `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @HexStringNoPrefix, 2)`, depending on whether or not the `'0x'` prefix is present in the source.  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Loxm9Zto).  *Thank you @ThomA for the correction.* (I have removed my earlier XQuery-based conversion  comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column is of type `image` (a poor-mans `varbinary(max)`) and you're trying to insert a string literal into it. You need to remove the single quotes around your string, because right now it's implicitly converting the *string literal* '0x504...' to varbinary, which isn't what you want.

You can see the effects of different types of inserts into an `image` column:

```
drop table if exists #vb
create table #vb
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    vb image
)

insert into #vb (vb) select '0x504'
insert into #vb (vb) select 0x504
insert into #vb (vb) select 'ThisWillGetConvertedToBinary'
```

Note, if your column were actually `varbinary` (which I know, you said you can't change the schema) it wouldn't allow this oversight to take place, and instead would throw an exception:

> 7, Level 16, State 3, Line 9
> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.